# Rust: How link unsafe for SAFESEH image

Tags: windows, rust

I need to link a library in a Rust program, which is an old and very important library of security algorithms, without source code, in a normal C++ program using the /SAFESEH:NO option, but in Rust, I can't find a way to set this option.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been resolved.
Create config file .cargo/config.
And set the rustflags.

```
[target.i686-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=/SAFESEH:NO",
]
```